# Azure DevOps Pipelines - Deploy Cancelled

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

We had a service connection certificate expire last week so we created a new service connection and since then the deploy stage in our yaml pipeline will not run, the UI reports a status of cancelled and when I go into the logs this is all I see:

[image]

I've enabled system diagnostics which yielded nothing.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I've tried deleting and creating the service connection but that has not worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after raging at the screen for a while, I remembered that I have a library that pulls in secrets from the key vault. The library was still using the original service connection (that was deleted). I updated the library to use the new service connection, re-authorised and the build then ran and deployed successfully.

An error message would of obviously been a massive help, its pretty bad that no logs appear in the build at all.

Comment: Thanks for putting the solution up here.  Just encountered the same problem today and was raging at the screen myself for a couple of hours before I found this post.

Comment: Not sure how long the library -> key vault functionality has been around but I imagine more people will experience this issue over the next few months as certificates expire, hopefully it helps more people or even better, Microsoft display a helpful error!!